# C# OleDbDataAdapter return null values in cases excel cell is not in Correct data type

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access, oledbdataadapter

I wanna read data from excel spreadsheet and insert them into Access data base(.accdb). there is a problem with data format in excel. some cells are in incorrect type. Correct format for example is 99999 and incorrect is 9999-888 . because of dash(-) ole data adapter return null values instead of text. how should i get whole cell block? 
I have tried change the cell format of excel from General to Text but the problem is still available.
thanks

```
string connectionStringExcel = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
using (OleDbConnection connectionExcel = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringExcel))
{ 
OleDbDataAdapter daExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM [priclist$]", connectionExcel);
DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
daExcel.Fill(dtExcel);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtExcel;
}
```

Comment: Modify the cell values to have a leading quote: `'9999`, `'9999-888`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider tries to determine variable type for each column, and assumes the majority type is the column type.

You can override this behaviour by specifying `IMEX=1` in the connection string, which uses text when encountering mixed-field types instead of setting the ones not matching the type to `Null`. Then you can handle the values in your C# code:

```
string connectionStringExcel = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;";
```

Read more about the IMEX property by following the link in the comment below

Comment: OK, but your link isn't very useful. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170343/reading-excel-sheet-using-ace-oledb-12-0-with-imex-1-not-working) explains it better.

Comment: @Gustav That link indeed explains it much better. Thanks!

Comment: i set both IMEX=1 And HDR=No and in this case my problem solved. why should i set HDR to No ?? you said i have to set HDR to Yes @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: @Hamed I certainly haven't said you should set HDR to no. The HDR setting is dependent on the Excel file you're working with...

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to transfer data from Excel to datagrid :

```
  private void btnreadExcell_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = string.Empty;
            string fileExt = string.Empty;
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
            Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)//if there is a file choosen by the user
            {
                filePath = ofd.FileName;//get the path of the file
                try
                {
                    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
                    dtExcel = ReadExcel(filePath, fileExt);//read excel file
                                                           // dataGrid.Visible = true;
                    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dtExcel.DefaultView;
                    datagridheader();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("error");}
    }

    public DataTable ReadExcel(string fileName, string fileExt)
    {
        DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string conn = string.Empty;

            if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)//compare the extension of the file
                conn = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';";//for below excel 2007
            else
                conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';";//for above excel 2007
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);//here we read data from sheet1
                    oleAdpt.Fill(dtexcel);//fill excel data into dataTable
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Clone();
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("error"); }
        return dtexcel;
    }
```

Comment: And so? In its core, it doesn't differ from that of the questioneer.

Comment: @Gustav There's a very relevant difference, the use of `IMEX=1` in the connection string. That's the solution. This code will likely work. Proper motivation as to why, however, is missing.

Answer (score 0):

My error has been Solved!!! with set both IMEX=1 And HDR=No. if you have changed your header in excel files(first row) use below code to solve same problem as i asked above. 
try this 
(two connection string have same meaning)

```
string connectionStringExcel = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1';"
```

Or

```
string connectionStringExcel = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +"T13970524.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1\";";
```