# How to prevent "Data mismatch" exception when OleDbDataReader reads multiple data types from excel? (General, Date, Time, Percentage etc)

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, datareader

I am working with excel and C#. I am trying to retrieve data using OleDbDataReader and print "something" if the "if" condition is met. 
The if condition works fine when the values in the excel cells are all texts. It prints out "something". But if the cell contains anything other type of data (right click excel cell and click cell formatting to see your type) like "Date" or any thing that has number in it, it doesn't check the if condition. An exception of Data mismatch is given.

According to my understanding, the OleDbData only works when there is text and throws exception whenever there is a different type of data.

This piece of snippet might provide an idea of what I am trying accomplish.

```
    OleDbConnection file1_connection = new OleDbConnection(file1_conn);
    file1_connection.Open(); 
    .
    .
    //other code irrelevant to the problem
    .
    . 

    string extractfile1Query = "SELECT * from [Sheet1$] WHERE " + file1_Header 
                                 + "='" + file1_rowVal + "'";
    OleDbCommand file_getRowCommand = new OleDbCommand(extractfile1Query, 
                                       file1_connection);
    OleDbDataReader file1_getRowReader = file1_getRowCommand.ExecuteReader();

     if (file1_getRowReader.HasRows)
                                      {

                                         Debug.WriteLine("something")
                                      }

//file1_Header and file1_rowVal are defined in other parts of code
```

I want the if condition to execute no matter what data type is in the excel cell and print "something".
Is there a work around for this since my data will contain different type of things like Date, Time, Number including text?

Comment: Can you provide an example where data type mismatch error occurred? Your current code only writes "something" if the reader has data rows, it doesn't check for data type of certain/every column inside the reader.

Comment: It's probably failing because you are looking for specific values in specific columns. Mixed data types aren't handled terribly well in OLEDB. You can ignore the header and ask it to return text but this does not always work as expected. You would then have to ignore the header in subsequent processing. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170343/reading-excel-sheet-using-ace-oledb-12-0-with-imex-1-not-working/46174530#46174530). If you ignore the header you can reference the columns using ordinal positions "Where Fn = value" E.g. "Where F1 = 'Joe'"